# Where option in Mongoose virtuals

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, virtual

I'm trying to get count of populated items in response, but I would like to filter populated data before counting.

Example

```
Team.virtual('membersOlderThan18', {
  ref: 'Member',
  localField: 'team',
  foreignField: '_id',
  count: true // Set `count: true` on the virtual
  options: { HERE IF AGE > 18 }
});
```

I'm not sure if this is possible at all since I can't find any examples on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, you can't. Virtuals are added after the data has already come back to your client, and before mongoose hands it over to you. MongoDB has no recollection of Mongoose virtuals, so they cannot be used in queries.

However, you can accomplish the same thing by just querying your `members` collection directly like so:

```
Member.find({
  teamId: '<the_team_id>',
  age: {$gt: 18}
});
```

Comment: I know about this way but thought it's maybe possible to do it this way. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer provided by @chrispytoes. However, you could also implement a query middleware (also called a 'hook') that allows you to run functions before or after a certain query is executed. In this case, you need a pre-find hook, that will be executed before the query is actually executed:

```
yourSchema.pre(/^find/, function(next) {
    this.find({ age: { $gt: 18 } });
    next();
});
```

I used a regular expression (`/^find/`) so that this middleware will execute for every find method in Mongoose (e.g. `find`, `findById`, etc.), but this really depends on the functionality that you want to achieve in your queries.